# Is there a limit to number of arguments in stringWithFormat?

Tags: string, cocoa, nsstring

I'm trying to compose an email using MFMailComposeViewController and I'm using a HTML string wich draws a table. It has 265 arguments so I have to pass it like this:

```
[mailViewController setMessageBody:
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"EMAIL_HTML_KEY", nil),

                                                date,

                                                object.foo[0],

                                                [object.bar[0] objectAtIndex:0],

                                                [object.bar[0] objectAtIndex:1], ... ...
```

When I run the app, it always hangs with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. It just stops at objc_msgSend after NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc according to the list shown in debugger so it seems clear that there's a problem with my string. The thing is... there isn't. I double checked both parts (the string itself and the list of arguments) and they were OK so I tried to cut the string to see where the problem was and I found that I only got the error when the string was big enough.

String="123456"  --> Error

String="123"  --> OK

String="234"  --> OK

String="456"  --> OK

So, it seems the HTML string is well formatted and the list of arguments is correct. The only thing I can imagine is that there's a limit to the number of arguments I can send to a NSString created with stringWithFormat. Is it right?. I would split the string but, being HTML code, I must pass it as a single string to mailViewController.

Any suggestion?. What am I missing?.

Comment: Well. I was doubting here. You answered the question but Michael's answer will be more useful to me to fix my problem so...  :D  In the end, I accepted your answer and gave Michael a +1. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your Header... NO. You can put any number of arguments.

And I can see

```
[mailViewController setMessageBody:NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString
```

Which should be

```
[mailViewController setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString
```

And you should use mutalbeString with appendString and a loop can do, as your index is seen as changing from 0 to 1....

Comment: Thanks Anoop. It's clear now. There must be an error somewhere then. I've corrected the typo, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your crash is likely because one of those random items being passed to the huge format string (e.g. "`[object.bar[0] objectAtIndex:222]`") would be an object the format string wasn't expecting.

Why not compose your HTML using a "`NSMutableString`" object, via the "appendFormat:" or "appendString:" methods and then pass the completely constructed string to "`[mailViewController setMessageBody: ]`"

Seems a lot less crazy than trying to instantiate an immutable NSString via a potentially easily busted format string fetched via NSLocalizedString.

Plus if you build your string via NSMutableString, you might be able to track down if there's any actual break in the HTML code you're trying to construct.

Comment: Thanks Michael. You're right. Using a NSMutableString seems a better approach. However, as I said, every part of the HTML code works correctly by itself so I think unexpected object is not the problems (besides, they are all same kind). I'm gonna try the mutable string and see if I can track down what's happening.

Comment: Now, this is weird. I've just do what you say and divided the big string into three independent strings with its own arguments. Then joined the three of it into one single pre-populated HTML string and passed it to the mail composer. Everything is fine now. Still, don't know what the error was.